# Unit test failing on Unable to find elements

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

This is first time I am putting unit test together and need some help in understanding why I am getting the following errors.

A) TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Visit my page. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

B)expect(received).toBeInTheDocument()

received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
Received has value: nulL

c) TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="aboutLink"]

Here is the piece of test I have in AModal.test.tsx

```
 import React from "react";
import AboutModal from "../../components/AModel";
import { render, screen, fireEvent, getByTestId } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("About Modal", () => {
  it("loads", () => {
    render(<AboutModal />, {});
    // Make sure the pop up has loaded
    expect(screen.queryByText("Welcome")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("Checks if link works", () => {
// expect(
    //   screen.queryByText("Visit the About Page for more info")
    // ).toBeInTheDocument();  ERROR B is coming here
    const { container } = render(<AboutModal />, {});
    fireEvent(getByTestId(container, "aboutLink"), new MouseEvent("click")); // Error C is coming here
    expect(screen.queryByText("About my document")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

And here is the piece of code from AModel.tsx component class.

```
     import { Typography, Button, Modal } from "antd";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./MyModal.module.scss";
import { RightOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import cookie from "react-cookies";
import Link from "next/link";

const MyModal: React.FC = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const { Text } = Typography;
  const hide = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const handleVisibleChange = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const hasVisitedBefore = cookie.load("hasVisitedBefore");
    if (cookie && !hasVisitedBefore) {
      setVisible(true);
      cookie.save("hasVisitedBefore", "true", {});
    }
  }, []);

  const content = () => {
    return (
      <div className={styles.popupcontainer}>
        <div className={styles.popupcontent}>
          <p>Learning Jest?</p>
          
        </div>
        <div className={styles.footer} data-testid="aboutLink">
          <Link href="/about">
            <a>
              <Text strong>
                Visit the About Page for more info <RightOutlined />
              </Text>
            </a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const popUpTitle = <span className={styles.popuptitle}>Welcome</span>;

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        title={popUpTitle}
        centered
        mask={false}
        className={styles.mystyle}
        bodyStyle={{ overflow: "auto" }}
        onCancel={hide}
        footer={null}
        visible={visible}
      >
        {content()}
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

export default MyModal;

Any help with this be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: I see. You cannot expect the test to pass if the modal is not visible. Cookies will cross-contaminate tests, hasVisitedBefore is set in test 1 and the modal is not visible in test 2. Mock `cookies`, `cookies.load` should return what you need. Clicking on aboutLink doesn't make sense because you don't run a server that could load /about page.

Answer (score -3):

Please try the following -

```
const {getByTestId} = render(<AboutModal />, {});
fireEvent.click(getByTestId("aboutLink"));
```

Comment: Could you explain what difference this would make?